# Audio is corrupted after joining videos with ffmpeg concat demuxer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-recording

I've concat or joined four video files using **ffmpeg concat demuxer** The video has no problem. But on audio side I am greeted with a bunch of error when I tried re encoding the final video. Here is the console output:

```
Output #0, matroska, to '../videos/nnnnc.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:35:10.922000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.80.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:35:10.929000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.80.100 libfdk_aac
    Stream #0:2: Subtitle: subrip (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 02:35:10.920000000
[aac @ 0x5653edc94b00] channel element 2.13 is not allocatedbitrate= 108.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=6.21x    
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5653edc94b00] channel element 2.13 is not allocatedbitrate= 678.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=5.96x    
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5653edc94b00] channel element 2.13 is not allocatedbitrate= 771.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=5.87x    
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5653edc94b00] channel element 2.13 is not allocatedbitrate= 693.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=2 speed=5.89x    
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x5653edc94b00] channel element 2.13 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
```

**ffprobe** output of source 1

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=hevc
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=1
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1001/24000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=93
color_range=tv
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=progressive
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24000/1001
avg_frame_rate=24000/1001
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=105
start_time=0.105000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:ENCODER=Lavc58.80.100 libx265
TAG:DURATION=00:00:03.108000000
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=subrip
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=unknown
codec_type=subtitle
codec_time_base=0/1
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=N/A
height=N/A
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=3108
duration=3.108000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:ENCODER=Lavc58.80.100 subrip
TAG:DURATION=00:00:03.105000000
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=2
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=4
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:ENCODER=Lavc58.80.100 libfdk_aac
TAG:DURATION=00:00:03.105000000
[/STREAM]
```

**ffprobe** output of source 2,3,4 (all are same source)

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=hevc
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=1
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1001/24000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=93
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24000/1001
avg_frame_rate=24000/1001
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=7
start_time=0.007000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:BPS=651629
TAG:BPS-eng=651629
TAG:DURATION=00:51:39.472000000
TAG:DURATION-eng=00:51:39.472000000
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES=74313
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng=74313
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES=252463300
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng=252463300
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP=mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng=mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC=2018-09-07 09:36:09
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng=2018-09-07 09:36:09
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=4
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=3
start_time=0.003000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:BPS=64000
TAG:BPS-eng=64000
TAG:DURATION=00:51:39.605000000
TAG:DURATION-eng=00:51:39.605000000
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES=72647
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng=72647
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES=24796844
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng=24796844
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP=mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng=mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC=2018-09-07 09:36:09
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng=2018-09-07 09:36:09
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=2
codec_name=subrip
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=unknown
codec_type=subtitle
codec_time_base=0/1
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=N/A
height=N/A
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=3
start_time=0.003000
duration_ts=3099605
duration=3099.605000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:BPS=65
TAG:BPS-eng=65
TAG:DURATION=00:49:21.500000000
TAG:DURATION-eng=00:49:21.500000000
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES=777
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng=777
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES=24256
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng=24256
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP=mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng=mkvmerge v9.6.0 ('Slave To Your Mind') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC=2018-09-07 09:36:09
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng=2018-09-07 09:36:09
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
[/STREAM]
```

**ffprobe** output of the joined video

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=hevc
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=1
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1001/24000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=93
color_range=tv
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=progressive
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24000/1001
avg_frame_rate=24000/1001
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=105
start_time=0.105000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:DURATION=02:35:10.922000000
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=4
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:DURATION=02:35:10.929000000
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=2
codec_name=subrip
codec_long_name=unknown
profile=unknown
codec_type=subtitle
codec_time_base=0/1
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=N/A
height=N/A
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=9310929
duration=9310.929000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:DURATION=02:35:10.920000000
[/STREAM]
```

The source 1 is generated via the following command to match source **2,3,4**

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -i sub.srt -map 0:v $amap $smap -t 3 -vf 'scale=1280x720,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=2' -r 23.98 -crf 22 -c:v hevc -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a 4 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -c:s copy wmv1.mkv"
```

The `$amap $smap` are PHP variable to match **2,3,4** configuration.

If I join video **2,3,4** without video **1** the output is fine. There is no error in encoding.

But when I include video **1** the encoding goes crazy by spamming my console with errors. No matter what I try or how differently I try. Outcome is same.

Concat demuxer command

`ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -c:s copy ../videos/nnnnc.mkv` 
 and list.txt

```
file 'source1.mkv'
duration 3

file 'source2.mkv'
duration 3099.6

file 'source2.mkv'
duration 3099.6

file 'source2.mkv'
duration 3099.6
```

***What am I doing wrong here?***

Comment: @llogan `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -c:s copy out.mkv`

Comment: The order of your streams do not match. Try `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24000/1001 -i image.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -i sub.srt -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=1280x720,fade=type=in:duration=1,fade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=2,format=yuv420p[v]' -map "[v]" -map 1 -map 2 -crf 22 -c:v hevc -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a 4 -c:s copy -t 3 wmv1.mkv"`

Comment: @llogan I didn't know that the ordering is also important. I'll try this now

Comment: I have tried that. But same result as before. It seems the generated audio is not identical to the other audios. I have tried many possible combination now and no luck :(

Comment: Can you provide a link to a small sample file that is similar to source 2,3,4?

Comment: @llogan https://letsupload.co/Rhv7/out2.2ch.mkv (stereo)
https://letsupload.co/Rhv8/out2.5.1ch.mkv (5.1)
  2 minutes file